# Android development on Fedora 19 64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, fedora

[image]

I have tried everything to get android SDK working on Fedora 19 64 bit. But still I get error that

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

In the image below I have created a new project.

So far I have tried

- sudo yum install libstdc++.i686  ncurses-libs.i686 zlib.i686
- sudo yum install redhat-lsb.i686
- yum install glibc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++.i686 zlib-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 libX11-devel.i686 libXrender.i686 libXrandr.i686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is somewhere under Eclipse preferences. You should check if the path of android_sdk is correctly linked. 
However, control in the project tree if the folder res is present.

Comment: The path to android_sdk is correctly linked and folder res is also present